# Add function to controller scope from outside of the controller definition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have AngularJS Material activated on my whole website. I have the controller definition block on each page, and fill the controller depending on the necessities of each individual page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $anyPageSpecificDependency) {

    //Page-specific functions and values

});
</script>
```

I have a sidenav toggle function that I'd need to work on every page. To not have to define the sidenav toggle function manually in the controller of every page, I want to add it in a piece of code that comes in the bottom include PHP file, though I don't know how to do it. Additionally, I'd need the toggle function to work with `$mdSidenav` dependancy, that's part of the main controller.

I would love to be able to do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $anyPageSpecificDependency) {

    //Page-specific functions and values

});
</script>

//The following is imported from an include file
<script type="text/javascript">
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {

    $scope.toggleSidenav = function() {
        $mdSidenav('sidenav').toggle();
    };

});
</script>
```

Though I can't do this, since when I define the controller the second time, it'll replace the first controller completely.

What is the best solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: You could consider encapsulating all sidebar-related functionality in a service, then you can depend on that service in your original controller without having to "extend" the controller definition, as you're trying to do. Simple example to illustrate what I'm talking about - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ygs1wFJDvlYagZqb

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I would need to not have to write anything in the controller. In the plunker there's the line `$scope.toggle = toggle;` and later a function declaration. I'd like to not have to do that. Is there a way?

Comment: If you want the sidebar toggle function to be available in any controller without having to explicitly wire up calls as in my first example, you can latch onto module initialisation and wire up the toggle onto `$rootScope`, making it available everywhere. However, I'd personally discourage this approach as I favour explicitness over implicitness. Here you go - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ygs1wFJDvlYagZqb

Comment: That works perfectly well, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! If you wish, please go ahead and write an answer so that I may select it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion of mine appeared to be of use so here it is as an answer:

You can take advantage of the [run()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) method available on module declarations to wire up properties on [`$rootScope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) (e.g. your sidebar toggle call). These properties will be available across each controller scope you define so there is no need to do any further explicit bindings.

[Here's a demonstration of the approach.](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ygs1wFJDvlYagZqb)